# Nested Observables and Mixed Promises

Tags: angular, typescript, promise, observable

I have an Angular 7 application which talks to a Firestore backend.

Im still trying to wrap my head around Promises vs Observables due to asynchronous processing.

Consider the following scenario. On loading a page, I need to check on some user permissions before deciding what it is we can show them.

As the permissions are dynamic and essentially on a page level, we need to get the Firestore entry for the current page, get the logged in Firestore user, the extended user information which I store separately, the permission name Im looking for, and then finally I can check if the permission for the user exists in page user permissions.

Yes, I should probably denormalise the data.

But you can see from this Im going to have to have several levels of query which I need to run first before displaying the data and Im getting really rather fed up of all the nested Observable subscriptions.

```
  checkGroupPermission(groupId: string, permissionName: string): any {
    this.userService.getCurrentUser().then(user => {
      this.userService.getUserForFirebaseUid(user.uid).subscribe(users => {
        if (users.length === 0) { return false; }
        this.groupUsersService.getAllForUser(users[0].id).subscribe(groupUsers => {
          const groupUser = groupUsers.find(cu => cu.groupId === groupId);
          this.roleService.getRole(groupUser.roleId).subscribe(role => {
            this.rolePermissionService.getRolePermissionsForRoleId(role.id).subscribe(rolePermissions => {
              this.permissionService.getPermissionByName(permissionName).subscribe(permissions => {
                if (permissions.length === 0) { return false; }
                const rolePermission = rolePermissions.find(rp => rp.permissionId === permissions[0].id);
                if (rolePermission) {
                  return true;
                } else {
                  return false;
                }
              });
            });
          });
        });
      });
    });
  }
```

I've also got about five different permissions to check. I want to tidy this up and was having a look at Promises vs Observables.

```
checkSomething(): Promise<boolean> {
  return this.myService.getData().then(data => {
    return true;
  }, reason => {
    return false;
  });
}

subCheckOfSomething(): Observable<boolean> {
  return this.myService.getFirebaseSubscribe().pipe(map(dataArray => {
    if (dataArray.length > 0) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }));
}
```

The two functions separately are fine, but if I try to call one from the other:

```
checkSomething(): Promise<boolean> {
  return this.myService.getData().then(data => {
    this.subCheckOfSomething().subscribe(data => { return data; });
  }, reason => {
    return false;
  });
}
```

doesn't work because an Observable is not a Promise

I know I could rewrite subCheckOfSomething to return a Promise instead:

```
subCheckOfSomething(): Promise<boolean> {
  return new Promise(resolve,reject) => {
  const data = this.myService.getFirebaseSubscribe().pipe(map(dataArray => {
    if (dataArray.length > 0) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }));
  data.subscribe(result => {
      resolve(result);
  }, err => {
      reject(err); })
  });
}
```

But this doesn't feel like the best solution. Are there any preferred ways of handling scenarios as this?

Answer (score 1):

**Using promises**

RxJs has a `toPromise`-method, which you can use to return a promise instead. The promise will resolve to the last emitted value of the observable once the observable completes.

```
subCheckOfSomething(): Promise<boolean> {
  return this.myService.getFirebaseSubscribe().pipe(map(dataArray => {
    if (dataArray.length > 0) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }))
  .toPromise();
}
```

**Using observables**

The problem is that you cannot break out of an observable chain early (you could do a hack and throw an error and catch that at the end, but I think this is not recommended), so you have these nested observable subscriptions. As you mentioned, you should tidy this up into several methods. You also only need to subscribe once at the very end and can pipe the rest of your methods like this:

```
  checkGroupPermission(groupId: string, permissionName: string): Observable<boolean> {
    this.userService.getCurrentUser().pipe(
      switchMap(user => {
      this.userService.getUserForFirebaseUid(user.uid).pipe(
        switchMap(users => 
          if (users.length === 0) { return of(false); }
          return this.groupUsersService.getAllForUser(users[0].id).pipe(
           switchMap(groupUsers => {
           // Basically you replace subscribe with pipe(switchMap())
        })
      })
    );
  }
```

Personally I think it is ok to have promises in certain parts of your application. This one seems to be most readable with `async`/`await` (not using `.then`) to me, so as long as you don't need some additional features like "abort this check and start a new one" (switchMap would be great for this) I would be fine with it.  Furthermore, you can easily transfer one to the other using `toPromise` (rxjs->promise) or the static rxjs-operator `from` (promise->rxjs).

Comment: Looks a lot cleaner than mine. Im just wondering if I should be using Observables throughout though?

Comment: I need to do some investigation on switchMap. Seems like a dark art. Problem then comes is that I need to call checkGroupPermission several times and wait for the results of all those. So I guess checkGroupPermission, as you rightly have, should be an Observable<> and then I can use something similar for each permission check call.

Comment: switchMap is two things in one:

1. like a flatmap on arrays

2. as soon as some new event comes in, the now old inner observable is "thrown away"